# Numerical Function

Tags: plotting, numerics, animation, numerical-value

I want to animate a Point moving on an ellipse, but the angle I need to use is a numerical solution from an epression. How can I get mathematica to just take the value from the animated nummerical solution and use it as a variable for my pointfunction?
This is my Code and this way it does not work. I think I have to remove the Set-Brackets around my Value for Psi.

```
ρ = 1; ε := 0.8 ; T := 10 π

curvE = ParametricPlot[{ρ/(1 - ε^2) Cos[ψ], ρ/Sqrt[1 - ε^2] Sin[ψ]}, {ψ, 0, 2 π}]

Animate[FindRoot[{ψ - ε Sin[ψ] == 2 π t/T} /. ε -> 0.8 /. T -> 10 π, {ψ, 0}], {t, 0, 10 π}]

Animate[Show[curvE, Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[
         Dynamic[{ρ/(1 - ε^2) Cos[FindRoot[{ψ - ε Sin[ψ] == 2 π t/T}, {ψ, 0}]],
              ρ/Sqrt[1 - ε^2] Sin[FindRoot[{ψ - ε Sin[ψ] == 2 π t/T}, {ψ, 0}]]}]]}]],
     {t, 0, 10 π, AppearanceElements -> None}]
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

```
FindRoot[t, {t, 0}]
```

Returns `{t -> 0.}`. You need to extract the numeric value, e.g.

```
t /. FindRoot[t, {t, 0}]
```

which returns `0.`. Inserting the needed `ψ /.` in your code makes it work:

```
Animate[Show[curvE, Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red,
  Point[Dynamic[{ρ/(1 - ε^2) Cos[#], ρ/Sqrt[1 - ε^2] Sin[#]}]] &[
    ψ /. FindRoot[{ψ - ε Sin[ψ] == 2 π t/T}, {ψ, 0}]]}]], {t, 0, 10 π, AppearanceElements -> None}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am really fascinated by mathematica, but iam still not very good at programming. This will help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
ρ = 1; ε = 4/5; T = 10 π;

curvE = ParametricPlot[{ρ/(1 - ε^2) Cos[ψ], ρ/Sqrt[1 - ε^2] Sin[ψ]}, {ψ, 0, 2 π}];

sol[t_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[{ψ - ε Sin[ψ] == 2 π t/T}, {ψ, 0}]

Animate[
 Show[
  curvE,
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, 
     Point[{ρ/(1 - ε^2) Cos[ψ], ρ/Sqrt[1 - ε^2] Sin[ψ]}]} /. sol[t]]],
  {t, 0, 10 π, AppearanceElements -> None}]
```